# работающий Data source на всех windows

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, entity-framework

Какой указывать data source, чтобы без установок localdb, mssqlserver и прочих работало на "чистых" windows (или вместо db нужно использовать а-ля xml?)?

Comment: sqlite как вариант, требует только библиотек в поставке, но при этом всё ещё sql.

Comment: В Винде вроде есть некая встроенная [ESENT](http://www.sql.ru/forum/1258289/esent-vstroennaya-v-windows-subd).

Comment: Смотря какие данные я считаю... Скажем, если у Вас пару строк, которые надо сохранить - тут я думаю лучше будет `JSON`, а если хранить приличное кол-во данных, то лучше использовать некую базу. Я к примеру на своем небольшом сайте использую `SQLite`, ибо он удобный, одним файлом, сейчас нашел аналог, говорят хорошая вещь [LiteDB](http://www.litedb.org/), вот думаю перейти на него. Я думаю и для ваших целей можно его приспособить!

Comment: Если вам нужна локальная БД, то советую sqlite и библиотеку из NuGet `linq2db`. Очень удобная и простая в развертывании, если один раз разобраться. Создайте файл БД в любом редакторе аля SQLite Studio или же создавайте БД и таблицы прямо в коде, динамически. Классы-сущности можно сгенерировать автоматически при помощи шаблонов, которые включаются в проект при установке NuGet пакета. Можно работать через LINQ, что заметно упрощает работу. Вот их репозиторий на гитхабе, на котором будет полезно почитать README: https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.

Comment: Для работы локальной БД с linq2db не нужно ничего, кроме пары библиотек, которые сами появляются рядом с исполняемыми файлами после компиляции. Ну и тут не нужно возиться с Entity Framework.

Comment: Если приложение уже написано, то `MS SQL Server` проще всего будет сменить на `MS SQL Server Compact Edition`

Comment: Вы меня немного не правильно поняли: мне требуется, чтобы мой exe(которое создает и работает с ДБ) работал у других, например, если я скину на другой комп, где нет sqlserver, то оно выдает ошибку(https://pp.userapi.com/c638718/v638718802/4c6c8/5C7tX0TfdXc.jpg). чтобы ее решить - нужно скачать такую же субд. у меня вопрос "что в таком случае делать\ какой data source указывать, чтобы пользователю не нужно скачивать субд?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Извините, что так не понятно задавал вопрос, в ином случае гугл бы дал ответ. ответ - "data source=(local)" либо вообще удалить эту строку

Comment: Дык если на другом компе нет SqlServer'а, это никак не заработает.

Comment: Тогда что в строке подключения писать? гуглить строку подключения ESENT? пытаюсь, но ничего не дает(мб из-за того что английский ис нот гуд)

Comment: В строке подключения писать адрес СУБД. Эта СУБД **должна** быть установлена у пользователя.

Comment: без установки - хранить в файле, так? спасибо